# Add one year to the date in each 3 iterations

Tags: php

I have an array of 6 elements, I would like to add one year after each 3 iterations

This is my array:

```
$lang = ["PHP", "JAVA", "Ruby", "C", "C++", "Perl"];
```

I tried :

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$i = 0;
foreach($lang as $l){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
       $date = $date->addYear();
    }
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `$i % 3`? And what is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1  I have an array $lang of 6 elements,  I want to loop over the array, and add 1 year to $date after each 3 iterations

Comment: Yes, you already said that, but what is your question about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in your code. You can just edit it to i > 0 to prevent it from running at startup. Since I don't know the Carbon class, I can speculate that date is a class in the beginning, but you may be equating it to a date in your loop. So you can try this:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$myDate = '';
$i = 0;
foreach($lang as $l){
    if($i > 0 && $i % 2 == 0){
       $date->addYear();
    }
   $i++;
}

$myDate = $date->year();

print_r($myDate);
```